# Where does the (-) sign come from in $\nabla \cdot \vec{J} + \frac{d \rho_v}{dt} = 0$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, charge, conservation-laws, conventions

Where does the (-) sign come from in $$\nabla \cdot \vec{J} = - \frac{d \rho_v}{dt}~?$$

Starting from $$I = \int_s \vec{J} \cdot d\vec{s} = \int_s \rho\vec{u} \cdot d\vec{s}$$
$$= \rho_v \int_s \vec{u} \cdot \vec{a_n} ds.$$

Now using divergence theorem:

$$\rho \int_v \nabla \vec{u}dV = \int_v \nabla(\rho \vec{u}) dV = \int_v \nabla \cdot \vec{J} dV$$

Now $I$ can be expressed as :

$$I = \frac{dQ}{dt} = \int_v \frac{d\rho}{dt} dV$$

Equating and removing the volume integral gives $\nabla \cdot \vec{J} = \frac{d \rho_v}{dt}$? Where in this derivation is a negative missing and is there a mathematical motivation for why it needs to be added? The only explanation I can think of is that current is defined in the opposite direction to the movement of electrons, so by convention do we add the negative?

Answer (score 5):

The mistake that gives rise to the missing *minus* sign is in your last step. The current you have calculated is outwards from the volume $v$, but you are equating it to the rate of *increase* of charge in that volume.

There are some other weird features of your derivation. For example, the line of mathematics following "Now using divergence theorem" doesn't actually use the theorem! The theorem tells you that
$$\int_v \mathbf\nabla\cdot\mathbf J\, \text dV=\int_S \mathbf J\cdot \text d\mathbf S$$

Comment: @BioPhysicist Thank you for improving the typesetting of my equation. "\cdot" is new to me, but clearly a good thing. Not de-italicising the d in d was sheer laziness on my part, but I'll try to be good in the future!

Answer (score 1):

The  normal flux integral is a measure of how much a qauntity flows outside the volume. The negative of this, is a measure of how much the qauntity flows INTO the volume, which is consistent on your volume charge integrals derivative being POSITIVE when charge ENTERS the volume